# How can I get Django inside a docker compose network to recognize the postgres service name while using PyCharm?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pycharm

I've been fiddling with my Dockerfile and Docker Compose to try and get PyCharm to be able to run and debug my django application.  I've identified that I need all services to be on the same network, and have put them on the same network, but when I go to execute the runserver command through my PyCharm configuration, I get an error that
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known`

I've tried adjusting the Dockerfile to expose environment variables inside of it, instead of in the compose file.  As well as grouping all the services into the same network.  I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to go from here, as most other StackOverflow questions relating to this tell me to do things I've already tried.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "2"
services:
    redis:
        image: redis:latest # redis
        restart: always
        logging:
            driver: "none"
        networks:
            - integration

    postgres:
        image: postgres:latest
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "5400:5399"
        volumes:
            - /usr/lib/postgresql
            - ./tmp:/dmp:ro
            - ./load.sh:/usr/app/load.sh
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: vagrant
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: vagrant
            POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
        logging:
            driver: none
        networks:
            - integration

    django:
        build: .
        command: "/bin/bash"
        working_dir: /usr/app/
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        volumes:
            - ./tmp:/tmp
            - ./:/usr/app
            - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh:ro
        links:
            - redis:redis
            - postgres:postgres
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: project.settings.docker_local
            DJANGO_DEBUG: "true"
            SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/authsock
        logging:
            driver: none
        networks:
            - integration

networks:
    integration:
        driver: bridge
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:latest
RUN echo "installing requirements"
COPY requirements/ /usr/app/reqs/
RUN pip install -r /usr/app/reqs/base.txt
RUN pip install -r /usr/app/reqs/local.txt
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.docker_local
COPY . /usr/app/
RUN echo "done"
```

I have hooked up PyCharm with the remote interpreter living inside the `django` service, and it is able to recognize all of the installed packages.

I have a docker-compose configuration for building the containers within PyCharm, and a Django Server configuration for running the runserver command on the Django service.

**Docker-Compose Config:**

[image: Docker-Compose Config]

**Django-Server Config:**

[image: Django-Server Config]

Finally, here is the relevant portion of my settings file, `docker_local.py`

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default='postgres://vagrant:vagrant@postgres/vagrant'),
}
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'
```

Any and all help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me, that when PyCharm executes the runserver command it's creating a new Docker image that isn't a part of the `integration` network, which could be causing the failure to resolve the `postgres` hostname.

Comment: Have you tried running everything first without using pycharm and just using a default network? Just to check if the postgres service spins up properly and that django is able to connect regardless of pycharm.

Comment: @BrianDestura Yes, I have a makefile that executes the runserver command on the docker container manually (docker exec -it etc etc).  That works fine and spins up properly, and is able to connect to the DB at hostname postgres

Comment: Have you tried adding a healthcheck to the postgres container? Because `depends_on` just checks if a container starts, but will not check (in this case) if the postgres instance is running and "accepting connections".

Comment: @JoeHoward I've attempted creating a similar setup and it worked fine. My configuration looks very much the same as yours, or at least I see no significant difference. I've uploaded the files (along with interpreter settings and run configuration) here: https://github.com/anemyte/so70159868 . Maybe try running it or see if there is any difference. Hope it'll help.

Comment: @anemyte Thanks for taking the time to do this, I'll check it out and confirm.